# Using 'of' for what purpose in a given sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, prepositions

I saw in a forwarded e-mail in my mail-box and while reading it, I do not comprehend the meaning of 'of' in this sentence. Can this 'of' be used as 'or'?

> the police using the number 101 **of** 112.

Comment: Maybe it's a typo (...101 *or* 112). Where did you get this sentence?

Comment: Normally the sentence is starting with: in case you see suspicious persons or situations, please contact the police [...].

Comment: Is it a typo? 101 and 112 look like typical emergency numbers in Europe.

Comment: Where did you read it? Provide the link. I don't find this sentence anywhere on the Internet (at least not on the search)

Comment: @DamkerngT. typo is **of** and not the numbers!

Comment: Oh, I thought you responded to helix...saying *is it a typo?*... :)

Comment: @DamkerngT. you mean all chance of having a typo since both the **keys** are nearest to each other? That's what I was thinking and putting it as an answer!

Comment: I think helix and I suspected this since the beginning. :-)

Comment: @DamkerngT. yep, it sounds like a misspelling character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, you made it clear. A forwarded **email** - very likely to have typos over something you read on the authentic sites (such as newspapers' sites etc.)

**Mostly** it's a typo and typos are likely to happen when the keys are **near**. On the Keyboard, the letter **r** and **f** are nearest and while typing, it's possible that the writer pressed **f** instead of **r**.

As others say here,

> the police using the number 101 **or** 112 - makes sense.